# Woocommerce PHP8 Error on Order Status change: id was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: woocommerce

```
    id was called incorrectly. 
Order properties should not be accessed directly. 
Backtrace: do_action('wp_ajax_wc_sa_mark_order_status'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WC_SA_AJAX::mark_order_status, 
WC_Order->update_status, 
WC_Order->save, 
WC_Order->status_transition, 
do_action('woocommerce_order_status_sent'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WC_Emails::send_transactional_email, do_action_ref_array('woocommerce_order_status_sent_notification'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WC_SA_Email->trigger, 
WC_Email->get_headers, 
apply_filters('woocommerce_email_headers'), 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WCJ_Product_By_User->sendemail_to_productowner_order_place_successfully, 
WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, 
wc_doing_it_wrong. 
This message was added in version 3.0.
```

Whenever I change the order status I get this message.
Who can point me in the right direction to get to the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to plugin Woocommerce Booster. In class-wcj-product-by-user.php line 81.

```
$useremail = $this->getProductOwnerEmail( $order->id );
```

I think it should be

```
$useremail = $this->getProductOwnerEmail( $order->get_id() );
```